# Vue-Router redirect always to /#/

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to integrate `vue-cli` with `webpack` template in an existing backend home-made framework. The websever is `apache`

I want the `vue-js` application to be loaded and mounted when the url `example.com/vue`.

When I go to this URL I can see the basic example `vue-component` but one second after I'm redirected to `example.com/#/`

**Do you have any idea how to solve this and where does the problem come from?**

#### Router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Hello from '@/components/Hello'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode : 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Hello',
      component: Hello
    }
  ]
})
```

#### Main.js

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to defined my path as the following `path: '/vue'` in the `router.js` file. If `vue-router` does not find the route it will redirect to `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Add router mode to "history"

```js
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../Index.vue";

const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: Home },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history", // Add this line
    routes,
});
```